# Resizing UIViews in UICollectionViewCells from another UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UIView that contains a UICollectionView, and each UICollectionViewCell in that collection view contains a UIImageView.

I need it so that each UIImageView in each cell can be resized based on a variable from the super view controller.

The variable, in this case named progress, should increase the size of the cells image view.

Currently I have the variable passed into the collectionview and am calling `reloadData()`, to set constants on relevant constraints I have on the imageviews. But this just recreates each imageview without proper animation. Also this method just doesn't seem correct.

I can pass the variable from the view controller into the collection view fine, the issue is how do I pass it into the cell. I keep getting nil whenever I try.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I think your title is misleading. Do you mean to resize UICollectionViewCells from a container UIView?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track passing the variable from the UIView to the collection view. From there, though, there's no need to pass a value into each cell (although that should work too).

Without seeing any code, I would suggest making the image view public, changing the constraints in the collection view directly under cellForRowAt, and then using

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, animations: { 
    cell.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: nil)
```

to animate the change. (Disclaimer: untested code).

Comment: Isn't that method only called when cells are queued?

Comment: @Stefan Cells are requeued every time they're recycled. If you scroll a cell far enough offscreen, it'll be dequeued, and then requeued when it's going to be visible again. Calling reloadData() forces every cell to be dequeued and requeued.

Comment: That was my first thought, reloading the collectionView with those new values. However, as previously mentioned I'm updating constraints using values from a pan gesture. That means I'd be calling `reloadData()` several times before the gesture completes. I've already thought of some other ways I could approach this, but I'm still curious if there's a way to properly do this.

Comment: @Stefan Ah, I wasn't aware you were using a pan gesture... That probably means unless you get great performance, this option is out. I'm not sure what a proper solution would look like, besides one that performs smoothly. If you do find one, please share for future reference.